# Copy table row in with jQuery only works for the first 3 column. And the delete function not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table and I want to clone the last line of it after the [Add New] link is pressed. The table has 8 columns. When I press the [Add New] link, only the first 3 column has the same value like the one above it. The delete function is also unable to delete row.

Here is the page when it loads.

[image]

Now, I key in values for PX, Date, and Place:

[image]

Then, when i click on the [Add New] link, new row appeared below. But only 3 columns are populated:

[image]

I want the row below to clone exactly the values from the previous row.

Here's the code of the table:

```
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("PxDataEntry", "PxAndTitle", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border:solid 1px green">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }

    <div><a href="#" id="addNew">+ Add New</a></div>
    <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>PX</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].px)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].sDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Place)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].PId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].FId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].createdBy)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].createdAt)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].PxStatus)</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (j > 0)
                        {
                            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                j++;
            }
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
}
```

Here is the script:

```
@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //1. Add new row
        $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
            var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
            var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

            var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
            $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
            $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                // Replaced Name
                var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                $(this).attr('name', newN);
                //Replaced value
                var type = $(this).attr('type');
                if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                    $(this).attr('value', '');
                }

                // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

            });
            $trLast.after($trNew);

            // Re-assign Validation
            var form = $("form")
                .removeData("validator")
                .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        });

        // 2. Remove
        $('a.remove').live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

    });
</script>
```

}

Comment: only three columns ? please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is because you empty your inputs values which are cloned i.e : `$(this).attr('value', '');` remove this line if you need values as well from your previous `trs` .Then, onclick of `a` tag you can simply use `.closest("tr")` to remove entire `tr` from table .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //1. Add new row
  $("#addNew").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
    var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
    var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

    var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
    $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function(i, val) {
      // Replaced Name
      var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
      var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
      $(this).attr('name', newN);
      //Replaced value
      var type = $(this).attr('type');
      if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
        //this line empty value of inputs 
        // $(this).attr('value', '');
      }

      // If you have another Type then replace with default value
      $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

    });
    $trLast.after($trNew);
  })

  $(document).on("click", "a.remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); //remove closest trs
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>PX</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="border:1px solid black">
    <td><input type="text" name="a[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sDate[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Place[0]" value="somthing"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Pid[0]" value="1"></td>
    <td>

      <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>

    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
<button id="addNew">Add</button>
```